# NVDA and JAWS screen reader is announcing unwanted text when readmore button is activated

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

NVDA-FF and JAWS-Chrome>, when read more element is activated while traversing through tab navigation then screen reader announces the unnecessary information along with the updated content. When read more element is activated in the arrow key navigation, for the instance, , screen reader announces as “ <> and <>”. Note: same goes with the read less element as well

```
<div class="pros-cons-block" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="pros-block">
        <h4>Pros-text</h4>
    <div>
        eachReview.pros
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cons-block">
        <h4>cons-text</h4>
        <div>
            eachReview.cons
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div v-show="eachReview" class="read-more">
    <button v-if="eachReview.readMore" class="readless" @click="readMore(eachReview)">
        <span aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span>
            <span v-if="eachReview.readMore">
                <span class="phw-visually-hidden">{{eachReview.headline}}
            </span>
        {{readLessButton.text }}
        </span>
    </button>
    <button v-if="eachReview && !eachReview?.readMore" class="readMoreButton" @click="readMore(eachReview, index)">
        <span aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span>
            <span v-if="eachReview && !eachReview?.readMore">
                <span class="phw-visually-hidden">{{ eachReview && eachReview?.headline }}</span>
                    {{ content.readMoreButton.text }}
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>

<script>
const readMore = (eachReview: any, index: number) => {
    eachReview.readMore = !eachReview.readMore;
    const focusElem = root.value.querySelectorAll('.glassdoorReviews .each-review')[index];
    if (eachReview.readMore) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const readLessButton = root.value.querySelectorAll('.read-less-button')[index];
            readLessButton?.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
            focusElem.querySelector('.pros-cons-block').focus();
            readLessButton?.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');
        }, 0);
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
            focusElem.querySelector('.readMoreButton').focus();
        }, 0);
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I’m sorry but I don’t quite follow. Could you please be more clear on what exactly you expect to happen, Placing `aria-live` regions only makes sense with javascript inserting content, which is not clear from your code. Can you share JavaScript, too?

Comment: @Andy added javascript related code